# How to combine list items into a dictionary where some list items have the same key?

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary

This is the file that I am working with called file1.txt

```
20
Gunsmoke
30
The Simpsons
10
Will & Grace
14
Dallas
20
Law & Order
12
Murder, She Wrote
```

And here is my code so far:

```
file = open('file1.txt')
lines = file.readlines()

print(lines)
new_list=[]
for i in lines:
   new =  i.strip()
   new_list.append(new)

print(new_list)

new_dict = {}
for i in range(0,len(new_list),2):
    new_dict[new_list[i]]=new_list[i+1]
    if i in new_dict:
        i[key] = i.values()

new_dict  = dict(sorted(new_dict.items()))
print(new_dict)

file_2 = open('output_keys.txt', 'w')
for x, y in new_dict.items():
    print(x, y)
    file_2.write(x + ': ')
    file_2.write(y)
    file_2.write('\n')
file_2.close()

file_3 = open('output_titles.txt', 'w')
new_list2 = []
for x, y in new_dict.items():
    new_list2.append(y)

new_list2.sort()
print(new_list2)
print(new_list2)
for i in new_list2:
    file_3.write(i)
    file_3.write('\n')
    print(i)

file_3.close()
```

The instructions state:

> Write a program that first reads in the name of an input file and then reads the input file using the `file.readlines()` method. The input file contains an unsorted list of number of seasons followed by the corresponding TV show. Your program should put the contents of the input file into a dictionary where the number of seasons are the keys, and a list of TV shows are the values (since multiple shows could have the same number of seasons).
>
> Sort the dictionary by key (least to greatest) and output the results to a file named `output_keys.txt`. Separate multiple TV shows associated with the same key with a semicolon (`;`), ordering by appearance in the input file. Next, sort the dictionary by values (alphabetical order), and output the results to a file named `output_titles.txt`.

So the part I am having trouble with 2 parts:

First is "Separate multiple TV shows associated with the same key with a semicolon (;)".

What I have written so far just replaces the new item in the dictionary.

```
for i in range(0,len(new_list),2):
    new_dict[new_list[i]]=new_list[i+1]
    if i in new_dict:
        i[key] = i.values()
```

The 2nd part is that in the Zybooks program it seems to add onto `output_keys.txt` and `output_title.txt` every time it iterates. But my code does not seem to add to output_keys and output_title. For example, if after I run `file1.txt` I then try to run `file2.txt`, it replaces `output_keys` and `output_title` instead of adding to it.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me make it more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to break down the problem into smaller sub-problems. Right now, it seems like you're trying to solve everything at once. E.g., I'd suggest you omit the file input and output and focus on the basic functionality of the program. Once that is set, you can go for the I/O.

You first need to create a dictionary with numbers of seasons as keys and a list of tv shows as values. You almost got it; here's a working snippet (I renamed some of your variables: it's always a good idea to have meaningful variable names):

```py
lines = file.readlines()

# formerly "new_list"
clean_lines = []

for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    clean_lines.append(line)

# formerly "new_dict"
seasons = {}

for i in range(0, len(clean_lines), 2):
    season_num = int(clean_lines[i])
    series = clean_lines[i+1]
    
    # there are only two options: either
    # the season_num is already in the dict...
    if season_num in seasons:
        # append to the existing entry
        seasons[season_num].append(series)
    
    # ...or it isn't
    else:
        # make a new entry with a list containing 
        # the series
        seasons[season_num] = [series]
```

Here's how you can print the resulting dictionary with the tv shows separated by semicolon using `join`. Adapt to your needs:

```py
for season_num, series in seasons.items():
    print(season_num, '; '.join(series))
```

Output:

```py
20 Gunsmoke; Law & Order
30 The Simpsons
10 Will & Grace
14 Dallas
12 Murder, She Wrote
```

Answer (score 0):

as I see you try to check if the key already exists in dictionary but it seems there is a mistake over there, you should check the value instead the index if it exists in dictionary and also you must check before putting into the dictionary and if it exits you can update current value by adding ; end the current value

```
for i in range(0,len(new_list),2):
    if not new_list[i] in new_edict.keys():
       new_edict[new_list[i]] = new_list[i+1]
    else:
      Update it here… like 
      new_list[new_list[i]] = new_list[new_list[i]] +";"+ new_list[i+1]
```